How to Set the Height of QScrollArea to Avoid Extra Spacing Between Buttons in PySide6?
I'm working on a PySide6 application where I have a QScrollArea that contains a QFrame (topMenu) with several QPushButton widgets. My goal is to have the buttons closely aligned one after another, without extra spacing. However, I'm encountering an issue where the QScrollArea or topMenu is expanding vertically, causing large gaps between the buttons.
Here's the relevant part of my code:
    # Create a scroll area for the topMenu
    self.scroll_area = QScrollArea(self.widgets.leftMenuFrame)
    self.scroll_area.setWidgetResizable(True)
    self.scroll_area.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
    self.scroll_area.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAsNeeded)
    self.scroll_area.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(37, 41, 48);")
    self.scroll_area.setWidget(self.widgets.topMenu)
    

    # Get the layout of leftMenuFrame
    layout = self.widgets.leftMenuFrame.layout()


    # Add widgets to the layout in the desired order
    layout.addWidget(self.widgets.toggleBox)  # Toggle box at the top
    layout.addWidget(self.scroll_area)  # Scroll area next
    layout.addWidget(self.widgets.bottomMenu)  # Instance Manager at the bottom

My Issue:
The problem is that when there are only a few buttons, the QScrollArea or the topMenu layout expands vertically, creating a large gap between the buttons. In Qt Designer, the buttons are aligned correctly, but once wrapped in a QScrollArea, this issue arises.
What I Need:
How can I ensure that the QScrollArea only grows as needed to fit the content, without causing the buttons to spread out and create unnecessary gaps? Any help on correctly setting the height of the QScrollArea or configuring the topMenu to avoid this issue would be greatly appreciated!
Required Output

Output Im getting

Hierarchy of the navbar:

it works fine, when i just use the topMenu frame alone, but i need to make it scrollable so that i can add more menu(buttons) dynamically. topMenu Frame is defined in QT Creator where as the scroll area is added manually through the code.

Sorry but right now your question is unclear and its code insufficient. Please provide a proper [mre], include at least a couple of images (what you get and what you expect instead), and also clarify how and why the scroll area should grow based on the contents, because the primary scope of a scroll area is to show itself in a suitable size depending on its surroundings and provide scrolling for what goes beyond its viewport: adapting its size to its contents may be possible, but it should only be done when appropriate and with some care about that behavior.

here i am trying to build a navbar like thing, and when the user clicks on that plus icon, it will add a new menu(button to it). so once it exceeds the hieght of that navbar, it will starts to shrink. so to avoid that, i have added the scroll area. As its mainly depended on UI files, its hard for me to share it here but i will share the project which iam using :https://github.com/Wanderson-Magalhaes/Modern_GUI_PyDracula_PySide6_or_PyQt6

Sorry but we cannot accept examples in full code, nor code existing on external resources, as they can be inaccessible to some or change in time (especially using repositories). The question must be self contained and always consistent even in the years to come. In any case, try setting the alignment of the top menu layout: self.widgets.topMenu.layout().setAlignment(Qt.Alignment.AlignTop). If it still doesn't work, then take your time, and create a proper MRE code with a basic UI based on your concept, and ensure it reproduces the problem.

adding self.widgets.topMenu.layout().setAlignment(Qt.Alignment.AlignTop) worked. thank you!!

Also note that you should generally avoid reparenting widgets created in the UI; instead, create the finished UI in Designer (except for dynamic content, obviously), and eventually implement it on the code side, possibly using widget promotion if subclasses are needed. Finally, you should never set generic properties on containers or complex widgets, as you did with scroll_area.setStyleSheet(). Such stylesheets must always use proper selector types.

sure, i will keep that in mind

Alternatively: 1. if the contents of the scroll area don't change (by adding more widgets at runtime), just add a spacer item at the bottom of the topMenu in Designer, or do the same in code with self.widgets.topMenu.layout().addStretch(); 2. if you do add more widgets to that, then add a vertical layout in Designer in place of topMenu and put itinside that layout, then add a stretch to that layout as above: in that way you have a nested layout, with the parent one having thetopMenu*pushed* by the stretch/spacer, and thetopMenu` layout can be used transparently.
